# How to destroy a record that could not be saved?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a createDocument action on a route. That action create a record and attempt to save it on the server.

If the server send back an error, I want to erase the record from the store.

This is a piece of code:

```
App.ProjectsmanageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    return this.store.find('document');
  },

  actions : {
    createDocument : function(){
      var store=this.store;

      var doc = store.createRecord('document', {
        title: "New"
      });

      this.set('currentDoc', doc);

      doc.save().then(this.newDocSuccess, this.newDocFailure);
    }
  },

  newDocSuccess: function () {
    this.transitionTo('editdocument', this.get('currentDoc'));
  },

  newDocFailure: function () {
    console.log("Error when creating document");
    console.log(this.get('currentDoc'));
    this.store.deleteRecord(this.get('currentDoc'));
    this.set('currentDoc', null);
  }

});
```

The error message is correctly shown in the console. But my record isn't deleted from the store anyway.

What could you find wrong with this code ? Is their another way to handle error on save of records ?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't deleted from the store?

Comment: The view keep showing the record and if I inspect the ember-data store with Embertools on Chrome, the record is still inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several testing, I understood this is more a Javascript problem than an Ember on. Since I was attaching my route functions as callback for then(), the "this" keyword in those function wasn't pointing to anything.

I had to transform the code like this

```
App.ProjectsmanageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // ...

  actions : {
    createDocument : function(){
      var store=this.store;

      var doc = store.createRecord('document');

      this.set('currentDoc', doc);

      // The context will change, register this as that
      that = this;

      // Registering anonymous function as callback that call the 
      // route's functions
      doc.save().then(
        function () {
          that.newDocSuccess();
        },
        function () {
          that.newDocFailure();
        }
      );
    },
  },

  newDocSuccess: function () {
    this.transitionTo('editdocument', this.get('currentDoc'));
  },

  newDocFailure: function () {
    var currentDoc = this.get('currentDoc');
    alert("Error when creating document");
    currentDoc.deleteRecord();
    currentDoc.save();
    this.set('currentDoc', null);
  }

});
```

Don't know, anyway, if their is a better way to deal with that issue than registering 2 anonymous functions in then().

Answer (score 1):

I totally missed the obvious, after `deleteRecord` you need to call `save`.  Additionally the store isn't necessary,  you can do it right on the record.

```
this.get('currentDoc').deleteRecord();
this.get('currentDoc').save();
```